# jquery .load renaming for form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

this is a a page A.html

```
<form name=form>
<input type=text id = txtA>
</form>
```

when i load using jquery to B.html
i load multiple times.

```
<form name=form>
<input type=text id = txtA>
</form>

<form name=form>
<input type=text id = txtA>
</form>

<form name=form>
<input type=text id = txtA>
</form>

<form name=form>
<input type=text id = txtA>
</form>
```

How can i rename the form name to form1,form2,form3...formN
so i can get this

```
<form name=form1>
<input type=text id = txtA>
</form>

<form name=form2>
<input type=text id = txtA>
</form>

<form name=form3>
<input type=text id = txtA>
</form>
```

when i submit i want to use php to retrieve the data.

```
for each form
    formi.txtA
```

this way i can get each form data uniquely.

Comment: I need to ask you this; you perform a `jQuery.load()` a few times?

Comment: yes. each time a 1 form is being load. user can press 1 time 5 time or 10 time. 5 button press = 5 form. 10 button press = 10form is being load.

Comment: I'm not sure having multiple forms is the best way to do this... maybe just multiple inputs with different names???

Comment: @user1397840 okay, let me update my answer then

Comment: i have a set of field for each object. like People{ Name,Age,DOB}. one person can key in example for a family 5 people data. so i can press add people button 5 time. there will be 5form of input field with same name, age, dob to be fill up by the person.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would rename all forms called `form` and postfix an increasing number:

```
$('form[name="form"]').each(function(i) {
    this.name = 'form' + (i + 1);
});
```

When you load the forms one by one, you need a different approach:

```
var renamer = (function() {
    var i = 1; // private counter

    // return public interface
    return function(base) {
        $(base).find('form[name="form"]').each(function() {
            this.name = 'form' + i;
            ++i;
        });
    }
}());
```

For every time you add a new form, you call this:

```
renamer('#divid');
```

Where `'#divid'` is the jQuery selector for the parent node where your form is in.

**Update**

It seems that you have multiple input fields that you dynamically load. Instead of loading a whole new form, just load the `<input />` fragment.

```
$(`#form`).load('http://www.example.com/inputfield?type=dob');
```

The server would then return a fragment:

```
<input name="dob" type="text" value="" />
```

This then gets inserted into one form, so you can submit it to PHP.

Comment: `.each()` provides it's own index. `.each(function(i){` - then you wouldn't need the increment counter =)

Comment: it also auto-increments, so you don't need to put i + 1 (unless of course, you want to start at 1 instead of 0)

Comment: @ahren I like starting at number 1, makes me look less like a developer ;-)

Comment: when i click submit button, i call the function to rename all the form? or upon each form is being load?

Comment: haha, I get what you mean - but it would probably cause problems on the server-side loop! (assuming there is one!)

Comment: @user1397840 ehm, okay, let me reread your question and figure that out for you

Comment: @user1397840 okay, i've updated the answer; i think you're looking for something simpler, the last section of my answer

Answer (score 2):

once all the loads are complete, you could run through a loop.

```
for(var i=0; i < $("form").size(); i++){
    $("form").eq(i).attr("name", "formName"+i);
}
```